# How to see XML value in HTML

Tags: .net, xml, repeater

I'm trying to bind XML to a repeater and an inner repeater. The issue I'm having is displaying the results on screen.

My simplified XML looks like

```
<EquipmentList>
  <Category Name="Microphone">
    <Item>
      <Description>
        SM58 Vocal Microphone
      </Description>
    </Item>    
    <Item>
      <Description>
        SM57 Instrument Microphone
      </Description>
    </Item>    
  </Category>
  <Category Name="Guitar">
    <Item>
      <Description>
        Gibson
      </Description>
    </Item>
  </Category>
</EquipmentList>
```

And I am binding in the Page_Load method

```
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/EquipmentPrices.xml"));
var nodes = xd.Descendants("Category").ToList();

this.Repeater1.DataSource = nodes;
this.Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And lastly, my HTML

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <strong>
                <%#Eval("Name") %> --- 
                <br />
        </strong>

        <asp:Repeater ID="InnerRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <!-- to do later -->
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>        
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The page is compiling and rendering, but I'm not seeing anything on the screen

I'm only asking about displaying the Category Name on the page. As you can see, I tried

```
<%#Eval("Name") %>
```

but this shows nothing on screen. However, Name is a property of XElement, so I'm guessing it doesn't even look for my attribute 'Name'. So, I tried

```
<%# XPath("@Name")%>
```

but this does result in a compiler error since `'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' must implement IXPathNavigable`

Can some one explain what syntax I need in the HTML to select the relevant element or attribute.